# How to extend C# DirectoryServices UserContext with msTSProfilePath, msTSHomeDirectory etc

Tags: c#, terminal-services, principalcontext

I need to read/write ActiveDirectory User object Terminal Services properties.
I tried this:

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "CA");

        using (context)
        {
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "CA\\vlekovic");
            if (user != null)
            {
                DirectoryEntry entry = (DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject();
                entry.Properties["msTSProfilePath"].Value = "";
                entry.Properties["msTSHomeDirectory"].Value = "";
                entry.Properties["msTSHomeDrive"].Value = "";
                entry.CommitChanges();
            }

        }
```

And I tried this:

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "CA");

        using (context)
        {
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "CA\\vlekovic");
            if (user != null)
            {
                DirectoryEntry entry = (DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject();
                entry.InvokeSet("msTSProfilePath", "");
                entry.InvokeSet("msTSHomeDirectory", "");
                entry.InvokeSet("msTSHomeDrive", "");
                entry.CommitChanges();
            }

        }
```

But nothing works.

I tried also with following property names:

- TerminalServicesProfilePath
- TerminalServicesHomeDirectory
- TerminalServicesHomeDrive

But no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Vojin

Comment: When you say the above code didn't work, can you elaborate? Did you, for example, get an exception?

Comment: Yes, I get following error: DirectoryServiceCOMExtension was unhandled. The attribute syntax specified to the directory service is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up and using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace, you can easily extend the existing `UserPrincipal` class to get at more advanced properties, like `Manager` etc.

Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you just define a derived class based on `UserPrincipal`, and then you define your additional properties you want:

```
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
[DirectoryObjectClass("Person")]
public class UserPrincipalEx : UserPrincipal
{
    // Implement the constructor using the base class constructor. 
    public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context) : base(context)
    { }

    // Implement the constructor with initialization parameters.    
    public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context,
                         string samAccountName,
                         string password,
                         bool enabled) : base(context, samAccountName, password, enabled)
    {} 

    // Create the "TermSrvProfilePath" property.    
    [DirectoryProperty("msTSProfilePath")]
    public string TermSrvProfilePath
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("msTSProfilePath").Length != 1)
                return string.Empty;

            return (string)ExtensionGet("msTSProfilePath")[0];
        }
        set { ExtensionSet("msTSProfilePath", value); }
    }
}
```

Now, you can use the "extended" version of the `UserPrincipalEx` in your code:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // Search the directory for the new object. 
    UserPrincipalEx inetPerson = UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "someuser");

    // you can easily access the TermSrvProfilePath now
    string path = inetPerson.TermSrvProfilePath;
}
```

The same way, you can also add the other properties you're looking for.

Comment: Error: PrincipalOperationException was caught - The attribute syntax specified to the directory service is invalid. If I change name of property to TerminalServicesProfilePath I get following error: PrincipalOperationException was unhandled: The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly the same way you told us.

I tried with an other fiel as

```html
    [DirectoryProperty("wWWHomePage")]
    public string wWWHomePage
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("wWWHomePage").Length != 1)
                return null;

            return (string)ExtensionGet("wWWHomePage")[0];

        }
        set { this.ExtensionSet("wWWHomePage", value); }
    }
```

But with the TermSrvProfilePath , it always return "empty" ...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: i can't comment his last reply :/ i haven't enought reputation